# In a jsp page where should we import jquery-ui?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have inherited a project in which in a page jquery-ui needs to be used. I do find the import at line no 2714. The line where I need to use jquery-ui is at line no 1084.I guess the original developer wanted to use a library which depends on jquery-ui & he needed that library much later in the page. Now I need it much earlier. Does the location of the line

```
<script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></scrpt>
```

has any bearing on its usability? Does it slow down loading of the page? Does hoisting work here that is if a function which depends on jquery-ui is invoked earlier javascript runtime will hoist jquery-ui library ahead of invocation? And what version should we use - the latest one? Can we invoke the library  in the head?

Comment: You're asking many different questions.  Scope it down to a single question, else it's too broad.

Answer (score 0):

You can and should "invoke" the library in the <head>

In terms of performance, where you reference the library on the page is marginally important, but a much bigger consideration is using a *minimized* version of jquery-ui